# Magento upgrade - mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: magento

Im trying to upgrade magento from 1.4.1.0 to 1.7
but I cant finish it
What did I do:
- copy and overwrite new files from 1.7 (on 1.4.1.0)
- clear var/cache
- clear var/session
- set files and directories permisions to 755 (info from magento instalation guide)

Now when I try to run install.php i get this error:

```
<code>
a:5:{i:0;s:308:"Error in file: "/home/klient.dhosting.pl/trezeta/trezeta.dkonto.pl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/sql/catalogsearch_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 W tabeli może być tylko jedno pole auto i musi ono być zdefiniowane jako klucz";i:1;s:1270:"#0 /home/klient.dhosting.pl/trezeta/trezeta.dkonto.pl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
 /home/klient.dhosting.pl/trezeta/trezeta.dkonto.pl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.7.7', '1.6.0.0')
 /home/klient.dhosting.pl/trezeta/trezeta.dkonto.pl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.7.7', '1.6.0.0')
 /home/klient.dhosting.pl/trezeta/trezeta.dkonto.pl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
/home/klient.dhosting.pl/trezeta/trezeta.dkonto.pl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
 /home/klient.dhosting.pl/trezeta/trezeta.dkonto.pl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
 /home/klient.dhosting.pl/trezeta/trezeta.dkonto.pl/public_html/app/Mage.php(682): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
 /home/klient.dhosting.pl/trezeta/trezeta.dkonto.pl/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";
</code>
```

any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you shouldn't need to run `install.php` if you are upgrading from a previous version of Magento, as Magento will execute the proper scripts for such.  That being said however, you are going from a very dated release to the latest, as you may have better results using incremental updates, per say 1.4 to 1.5 first and so on.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error when I installed a new 1.6.2.0 on my local machine and imported a DB from a 1.4.? version. The DB upgrade process kept failing when I tried accessing the index.php via the browser.

The following worked for me, per this user swifty_'s post here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/248462/

- cd to your `magentodir`
- clear the var/cache and var/session;
- run `php -f shell/compiler.php clear` and then make sure it's disabled by running `php -f shell/compiler.php disable`
- run `./mage config-set preferred_state stable`
- reinstall all the Mage community modules: `./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force`
- restart my Apache and MySQL servers
- run `php index.php` -- this is what causes the upgrade process, and if done from a browser window, can be halted by timeouts, and then the DB transaction fails.

Good luck.